# Hadoop dfs error : INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost

Tags: hadoop, localhost, cluster-computing

I have successfully setup a Hadoop cluster with 6 nodes (master, salve<1-5>)

- Formatted the namenode -> done
- Starting up and shutting down cluster -> works fine
- Executing "hadoop dfs -ls /" gives this error -> **Error: INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost**

I tried to see the services running using:

```
sudo netstat -plten | grep java
hduser@ubuntu:~$ sudo netstat -plten | grep java
```

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50070           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       93307       11384/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:44440           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       92491       11571/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:40633           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       92909       11758/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50010           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       93449       11571/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50075           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       93673       11571/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50020           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       93692       11571/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:40485         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       93666       12039/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:44582           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       93013       11852/java
tcp        0      0 **10.42.43.1:54310**        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       92471       11384/java
tcp        0      0 **10.42.43.1:54311**        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       93290       11852/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50090           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       93460       11758/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:34154           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       92179       11384/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50060           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       94200       12039/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50030           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       93550       11852/java

Its the master IP binded to port 54310 and 54311 and not the localhost(loopback).

The conf-site.xml has been properly configured:

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
<value>/home/hduser/hadoop/tmp</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://master:54310</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Why is it expecting localhost to be binded to 54310 rather than the master hich I have configured here. Help appreciated. How do I resolve this ??

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, someone added the older hadoop(1.0.3) bin directory into the path variable before I had added the new hadoop(1.0.4) bin directory. And thus whenever I ran "hadoop" from the CLI, it executed the binaries of the older hadoop rather than the new one.

Solution:

- Remove the entire bin path of older hadoop
- Shutdown cluster - Exit terminal
- Login in new terminal session
- Startup node
- Tried `hadoop dfs -ls /` -> Works fine !!!! Good lesson learnt.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like many people ran into this problem.

There might be no need to change /etc/hosts, and make sure you can access master and slave from each other, and your core-site.xml are the same pointing to the right master node and port number.

Then run $HADOOP/bin/stop-all.sh, $HADOOP/bin/start-all.sh on master node ONLY. (If run on slave might lead to problems). Use JPS to check whether all services are there as follows.

On master node:
4353 DataNode
4640 JobTracker
4498 SecondaryNameNode
4788 TaskTracker
4989 Jps
4216 NameNode

On slave node:
3143 Jps
2827 DataNode
2960 TaskTracker

Answer (score 0):

In addition, check your firewall rules between namenode and datanode